# Trait using for extending childclasses

Tags: php, oop, traits

I've the following classes and trait:

```
class BasicModel {
   public function update() { /* some code */ }
}

class Task extends BasicModel {
   use TagTrait;
}

class User extends BasicModel {}

trait TagTrait {
   public function writeTag() { /* some code */ }
}
```

The BasicModel-Class is extending Task and User (and more). Task can use the TagTrait which defines a function to write tags to every using type. User can not use TagTrait. The goal should be, if I call update() on Task, the trait should be called also, to do the work for tagging. I know two possible ways. I could overwrite the update-function in Task to call the writeTag-function, or I have to check in BasicModel's update(), whether or not the extending class uses the TagTrait and if yes call the writeTag-method. First way is not really smart because I've to do the same work many times. Second way looks also not really good to me, but I don't know a better way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using a trait?

Comment: @PeeHaa Because the function body of writeTag is always the same. First I used interfaces, but it was always only copy+paste. A global function was the other option, but I wanted to access the instance-variables, and the problem would be the same if i would place it global. What would you use?

Comment: I would inject the thing whatever it is as a dedicated object.

Answer (score 1):

A bit ugly but combineable, overwriteable

```
class BasicModel {
    private static $updateMethods = [];
    public final function update() {
        echo "Start update\n";
        $c = get_class($this);
        if ( !array_key_exists($c,self::$updateMethods) ) {
          self::$updateMethods[$c] = preg_grep('/^_traitUpdate_/', get_class_methods($this));
        }
        foreach (self::$updateMethods[$c] as $m ) {
            $this->$m();
        }
    }
    protected function _update() { echo "Update Basic\n";}
}

class Task extends BasicModel {
    use TagTrait;
}

class User extends BasicModel {
}

class OtherTaggable extends BasicModel {
    use TagTrait,NoteTrait;
}

class TaskChild extends Task {
    use TagTrait;
    protected function _update() { echo "Update TaskChid overwriten\n";}
}

trait TagTrait {
    public function writeTag() { /* some code */ }

    public function _traitUpdate_TagTrait() { echo "TagTrait update\n"; }
}

trait NoteTrait {
    public function writeNote() { /* some code */ }

    public function _traitUpdate_NoteTrait() { echo "NoteTrait update\n"; }
}



$U = new User();
$T = new Task();
$O = new OtherTaggable();
$OC= new TaskChild();

$U->update();
echo "-\n";
$T->update();
echo "-\n";
$O->update();
echo "-\n";
$OC->update();
```

Comment: Yeah, this is working as long as I don't overwrite the update()-method within a child-class. But if I do so, the TagTrait-update() would not be called. I should have mentioned this side-problem.

Comment: @MIB yes, but if `class TaskChild extends Task {
    use TagTrait;
    public function update() {  parent::update();echo "TaskChild update\n"; }
}` it works again

Comment: Okay thats right - but i fear i have to say that TagTrait isn't the only one. :( There are overall five traits with the same concept idea (ExtendDataTrait, AttachFileTrait, ConfigurateObjectTrait, AddNoteTrait) applying functionality for ~20 different types. None uses all traits, but every type uses a selection of traits out of this list. I would have to build up to 5 ChildClasses of every type-class extending each other to achieve this workflow. No chance to build a smarter way?

Comment: @MIB i have tried to add another and stuck there, what my first thought is `trait X { function _traitUpdate_X() } trait Y { function _traitUpdate_Y() }` and in update get those with reflection and call them, but seems ugly

Comment: Thank you. Your idea goes in the same direction as my second mentioned way - checking if trait is used by childclass and if yes than call the handling method. The difference you made is the _update()-method. This solves the problem i had with the overwriting. Its really  ugly looking code, but at the moment the smartest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it via **Composition**:

```
class BasicModel {
   public function update() { echo 'Update'; }
}

class Tag {
   public function writeTag() { echo 'Write';  }
}

abstract class TaggingModel {
    private $model;
    private $tag;

    public function __construct(BasicModel $model, Tag $tag) {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }

    public function update() { 
        $this->model->update();
        $this->tag->writeTag();
    }
}

class User extends BasicModel {};
class Task extends TaggingModel {}

// Prints `Update`
$user = new User();
$user->update();

// Prints `Update Write`
$task = new Task(new BasicModel(), new Tag());
$task->update();
```

The limitation is that BasicModel `update` method has to relate on its own properties.

If we want to skip the above limitation we can implement combination of **Composition and Inheritance**:

```
class BasicModel {
   public function update() { echo 'Update'; }
}


class Tag {
   public function writeTag() { echo 'Write';  }
}


class TaggingModel extends BasicModel {
    public function __construct(Tag $tag) {
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }

    public function update() {
        parent::update();
        $this->tag->writeTag();
    }
}

class User extends BasicModel {};
class Task extends TaggingModel {}

// Prints `Update`
$user = new User();
$user->update();

// Prints `Update Write`
$task = new Task(new Tag());
$task->update();
```

Comment: Possible solution yes, but if i want to build more than one trait of same conceptual idea but with the problem, that not every type would use all traits, I'll could not use inheritance. How would I solve this?

Comment: Your solution with overwriting the parent's method seems legit to me (if it's a one time case). If it's a repeating pattern, you can separate it as it's mentioned in my answer.